# What to do to update SVN?

Tags: svn, windows-10, tortoisesvn

I have a problem updating data on our company SVN.

Trying to update via the "Update" function, I get the following error:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jif3A.png]

Going to the "Cleanup" function, I get the following error:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJw6C.png]

I don't know what is caused. It even suspends ESET protection.

Have any of you encountered such a mistake?

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: can you provide English error messages or translate it for us?

Comment: If you're just missing some .svn\pristine files you can always get a clean checkout and then copy them all over into the broken working copy from there. But it might be easier to just get a clean working copy and copy your changes into it then commit from there.

Answer (score 1):

Please double-check you don't have some other piece of software (such as you IDE) doing stuff on the same working copy. If that doesn't solve the issue, then your working copy is possibly corrupted (the format is not rock solid). Grab a fresh check out in an empty folder and recover pending local changes (if any) from the original folder with your favourite file comparison tool.